# Refunding of payments if scam

Tags: fraud

I was called by someone when I tried to withdraw my money, who works for Bluesave,  but when I log in the platform was Optima platform and when to proceed for withdraw he send me to Jubiter page. The problem is that the first time when I opened my account was in March and I put a deposit of 275 euros. Today I requested my money back and he took another 275 euros from my account saying that is the verification procedure. And then he said, in order to send me the full amount in my bank account I have to buy some bitcoins for about another 500 euros. I am concerned about this transactions an I want to ask if this is the correct procedure in order to get my money back?..If not what can I do to get them back? Thank you

Comment: Don't pay them, report them to your local authorities.

Comment: Bluesave is a very obvious scam. "High percentage, risk free deals on saving accounts that will provide you with a monthly return of up to 45% of your capital." That's like claiming to be able to teleport to Mars for lunch.

Answer (score 4):

> **I want to ask if this is the correct procedure in order to get my money back?**

No.

You are being tricked by a criminal. A confidence trickster (con-man). It is a common type of fraud or scam.

> **If not what can I do to get them back?**

There's no way to get the money back. Bitcoin transactions are not reversible and cannot be undone or cancelled.

You can report this fraud to your local police so that the police crime statistics are more accurate - but they won't be able to recover your money for you.

You will be contacted by people who say they, or someone they know, can get your money back. They are lying to you. They also will eventually ask you to pay release fees, transfer fees, decryption fees or some other kinds of fees they invent. None of these fees are real. I urge you to ignore such offers and accept that your money is gone and move on with your life.

> **Today I requested my money back and he took another 275 euros from my account**

From what you say, your Bluesave and/or Optima and/or Jubiter accounts are no longer under your control, any money in one or all of  those accounts is now under the control of a criminal. It will be best to not ever use these accounts again. Even after changing passwords, they cannot be guaranteed to be safe.

If I were you, I would make a list of all accounts the criminal might know of, then I would set aside any information given by the criminal (phone numbers and email addresses etc) and independently find out the true contact details for the businesses that provide those accounts (but be aware that some may be fake businesses run by the criminal), then I would ask, in writing, each business to close the account explaining that you are the victim of fraud.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it. Kind regards